# Log4j doesn't create audit log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, audit-logging

I want to track audit logs to separate file `audit.log`

I have the following configuration for log4j

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Audit logs
log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.A2.File=/home/michal/audit.log
log4j.appender.A2.Append=true
log4j.appender.A2.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.A2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - AUDIT - %m%n
```

In my code I'm calling

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("A2");
logger.info("audit test");
```

But audit log file is not created. When I put `A2` level to rootLogger, the file is created but it is full of logs from `stdout` target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A2 is an **appender** not a **logger**. You need to add a line to your log4j configuration to define a **logger** that writes to your **appender** and then you can write to that in your java code.

In your config

```
log4j.logger.audit=INFO, A2
```

and in your java code

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("audit");
```